# Correct way to use "NOT IN" Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, People, and Vehicles.  Vehicles belongs to people.  Im trying to check if a person does not have a vehicle.  I was attempting to do this by joining People and Vehicles, and displaying the persons ID that is NOT IN Vehicles.person_id.

This is returning nothing, and has me wondering if there is something I did wrong, or if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Query is below

`Select People.id
From People
INNER JOIN Vehicles
on People.id=Vehicles.person_id
where People.id NOT IN Vehicles.person_id;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join to figure out the persons with no vehicles

```
  Select distinct People.id 
  From People 
  LEFT JOIN Vehicles on        People.id=Vehicles.person_id 
  where Vehicles.person_id is NULL
```

Comment: You may want a `SELECT DISTINCT` here if one person is allowed to have many vehicles.

Comment: this executes much faster than `where not in`

Answer (score 2):

`NOT IN` can have [issues with `NULL` values](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-NOTIN), and should probably be avoided for [performance reasons](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/) if the subquery is very large.

Try `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM People p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Vehicles v
    WHERE v.person_id = p.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution, using sets:

```
Select id From People
except
SELECT person_id FROM Vehicles
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Subquery as below:

```
Select id 
From People
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT distinct person_id
                 FROM Vehicles 
                 WHERE  person_id IS NOT NULL)
```

select all people who are not in (by `Select id From People WHERE id NOT IN`) the List of all the people who has vehicle by `SELECT distinct person_id FROM Vehicles` (you could avoid null as well here if you want).

Comment: ahh, nice.  This doesnt return anything though.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @ColtonSeal: you most probably have `null` values in the `person_id` column. Use `select person_id from vehicles where person_id is not null`)  in the sub-select (the `distinct` is useless)